# Will a report built in BIDS 2008 work with SSDT 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, bids, sql-server-data-tools

I have couple of reports built on SQL Server BIDS using SQL Server 2008 R2. No we are creating a new database on SQL Server 2014. Since it will be some time before I can actually test it, I would like to know if a report that was built on BIDS can be uploaded to Reporting Server of SQL Server 2014?

Assuming that the query, table name, database name etc remains the same?

The main issue is the length and width of the report and other parameters have been perfected after a lot of hard work and I don't want to go through that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, with a small but.

MSDN actually has some pretty good information on this. From [Upgrade Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674.aspx), I think the key points are:

> When you open a report in Report Designer in SQL Server Data Tools
>   (SSDT), the report definition is upgraded to the currently supported
>   RDL schema. When you specify a SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2
>   report server in the project properties, the report definition is
>   saved in a schema that is compatible with the target server.

and:

> When you upgrade a Reporting Services installation to a SQL Server
>   2014 Reporting Services (SSRS) installation, existing reports and
>   snapshots that have been published to a report server are compiled and
>   automatically upgraded to the new schema the first time they are
>   processed.

**SQL Server 2008 R2** is expressly noted as upgrade compatible.

The article also notes:

> After a report is upgraded locally or on the report server, you might
>   notice additional errors, warnings, and messages.

i.e. certain version may have items in the report definition that cannot be handled in 2014.

However, it's important to note that since 2008 R2, there have actually been minimal changes to the actual report schema definition (RDL specification). This means that going from **2008 R2** -> **2014** is likely to work without too many issues, if any.

Your best bet is to open the **2008 R2** reports in SSDT, then run a preview - this should highlight any issues. But given the versions you are dealing with, it's highly likely this will be successful. Without testing your specific reports it's impossible to be definitive, but I think it is worth pursuing.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I will get a chance to test it either today or tomorrow.

Comment: I tried to run the same report in SSDT but it ends up that it is not rendering my VB.Net code. My code turns a barcode in an image and uses System.Drawing reference class. 
The report is not giving any errors, the image is just absent when I preview the report.

Comment: Ian, it was an issue with the barcode font. Its solved now thank you for your support.